# Strange exceptions on deleting user in asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net mvc core web app with default model classes and SQLite as DB.
I am deleting users by following code:

```
var user = await _dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
try
{
    await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Deleting most users going ok, but for some users I got different exceptions, like: `System.ObjectDisposedException` or `System.InvalidOperationException: 'BeginTransaction can only be called when the connection is open.'` In such cases user is not deleted. Why the same code could work so strange for different users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I have class which is also stored in DB:

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lon { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

So, if I am trying to delete user, which have coordinates - I got an error. 
I have to delete user's coordinates first:

```
            var coordinates = _dbContext.Coordinates.Where(x => x.User == user).ToList();
            _dbContext.Coordinates.RemoveRange(coordinates);
```